# firebase storage and upload from php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a php application and from this i need upload images to google `firebase storage`. I had seen snippets that write to and read from realtime database but couldnt find any code that upload from php to `firebase storage`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Tismon Varghese

Answer (score 4):

You can get started by using their official documentation at
[The storage documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-storage.html) and [An easier to use SDK within a Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/src)
You can explore the two for other information. So to get started on how I did mine. I was working on a laravel project though.

You have to install this package **composer require kreait/firebase-php**

Then also read the setup steps at [Package Setup](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html)

```
     $storage = app('firebase.storage'); // This is an instance of Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient from kreait/firebase-php library
     $defaultBucket = $storage->getBucket();
     $image = $request->file('image');
     $name = (string) Str::uuid().".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension(); // use Illuminate\Support\Str;
     $pathName = $image->getPathName();
     $file = fopen($pathName, 'r');
     $object = $defaultBucket->upload($file, [
          'name' => $name,
          'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
     ]);
     $image_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/'.env('FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID').'.appspot.com/'.$name;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using the [Google API Client PHP library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) for this, as Firebase Storage is backed by Google Cloud Storage. Firebase Storage doesn't provide a PHP client for front end code though.

From the [GCS PHP example code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples):

```
// composer autoloading
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// grab the first argument
if (empty($argv[1])) {
    die("usage: php listBuckets [project_id]\n");
}

$projectId = $argv[1];

// Authenticate your API Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Storage::DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

/**
 * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the list of buckets in your project.
 */
$buckets = $storage->buckets->listBuckets($projectId);

foreach ($buckets['items'] as $bucket) {
    printf("%s\n", $bucket->getName());
}
```

Comment: This snippet is for reading the files already uploaded. How about uploading new images to Firebase storage? Can't find any examples of that.

Comment: I want to use firebase-storage in core-php project, i tried to use above given example, but it is showing errors